# Let $\{x_{n_i}\}$ be a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$. Then $n_i\leq i$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am supposed to either prove or disprove this statement. Here is what I did to disprove, could I get some feedback on what I did?

Proof. $\ $ Suppose $n_i\leq i$, $\forall \ i\in\mathbb{N}$. 
Then, consider the sequence $\{x_n\}=\{\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\cdots,\frac{1}{n},\cdots\}$, with subsequence $\{x_{n_i}\}=\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{6},\cdots,\frac{1}{2n},\cdots\}$. 
Where $x_{n_i}=x_{2i}$, so $n_i=2i$. Then it must follow that $n_i=2i\leq i$ which is impossible.

Thus, the statement is false by contradiction. $\ \mathbb{QED}$

One thing I am unsure if I did correctly was my jump from $x_{n_i}=x_{2i}$ to $n_i=2i$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Why is it not enough to just show a case where the conclusion fails?

Comment: Because I'm dumb and misread what you were saying. For some reason I read it as being a proof rather than a counterexample. Sorry.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer oh haha all good! So what I have works then?

Comment: Yeah, by my eye it works. (Though I think we can probably agree my judgment isn't the most reliable at the moment. :p)

Answer (score 1):

What you think you did incorrectly, is in fact correct. See, a sequence is a function from $\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$. Therefore, because your function is one-one (this is by definition, because if $i \neq j$ then $\frac 1i \neq \frac 1j$ so $x_i \neq x_j$), the step $x_{n_i} = x_{2i}$ implies $n = 2i$ is true by definition.

The rest is clear enough, and you are right.

---

In fact, somewhat the opposite is true : if $x_{n_i}$ is a subsequence of $x_n$ then $\boxed{n_i \geq i}$ for all $i$. The proof is fairly simple, because $n_i$ are chosen to strictly increase and $n_1 \geq 1$, so you can do this by induction.